# fast method calc count black pixel, Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need calc count black pixel in each line of the image. My code:

```
 from PIL import Image


im1 = Image.open("2.png")

def bw_filter(threshold=127):
    def table_gen(x):
        return 0 if x < threshold else 255
    return table_gen

new = im1.convert("L").point(bw_filter(200)).convert("1")

shir = new.size[0]
vys = new.size[1]

pix = new.load()
str_mas = []

for y in range(vys):
    sum_str = 0
    for x in range(shir):
        sum_str += pix[x,y]/255
    str_mas.append(shir - sum_str)
```

This is slow. 5 second on image size A4. Faster method exists?

Comment: What is your result? `str_mas`? But you wanted to count black pixels? I can't tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: My result - str_mas. It contains count black pixel in every line of  image. Ultimate goal - find all text string on image. If string contains a lot of black pixel - this is part of text string.